# how to display dialog builder in front of floating window

Tags: android

[image]

Hi....

I have an activity and a service in which in this service I am running a 
windowmanager dialog (floating window)

Purpose of this is that.

I want to display this window every activity I visit so this floating window can also me minimize just like facebook messager except fb messenger is another application from facebook

then there are scenario that I want to display a dialog builder in my app my the problem is that since I am using floating window the dialog I display wont display in front of floating instead it just display at the back since I know floating window is also a dialog and my dialog display at the back of floating window,

my question is that is there any way to display my dialog in front of floating window?

I also tried displaying another floating window it's works but it will cause a lot of problem also

thanks for the help in future!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use WindowManager. [WindowManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.html)

For example, you can write code. Like this,

```
View v;   // your dialog view
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,0,0,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD  
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON    
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,    
        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);                                       
params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;       
WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
windowManager.addView(v, params);
```

Maybe you need permission,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
```